# Wordpress Htaccess allow certain IP addresses issue with SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have restricted access to my wp-login.php and have allowed to only one IP and it worked fine till I moved my site to SSL. Now if i try accessing wp-login.php from a different IP without https, its showing the forbidden. But if i try https:// www . mysite . com / wp-login.php then i am able to get the login page.

I'm not able to identify here whats the issue. Any help ?

Here is my htaccess part

```
<files wp-login.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</files>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

One more info, the site was originally created without SSL, and then later moved to SSL.

Comment: Please show your full .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you write it in your first post? It's not easy to read.

Comment: @Pierre-Jean : done, please check.

Comment: Can you try to change the order of the two parts of your .htaccess and run it?

Comment: already tried that, didn't worked.